# Is there a way to report (bootstrap) model results in Stata without a variance-covariance matrix?

Tags: stata

I have written a program in Stata to perform a cluster bootstrap-t procedure for estimating t-statistics and parameter confidence intervals.  The goal of the program is to use t-tests and to create CIs that are robust to cluster correlation, even for small numbers of clusters.  For the curious, this is built off the "cluster bootstrap-t with asymptotic refinement" procedure described in Cameron, Gelbach, and Miller (2008): "Bootstrap-Based Improvements for Inference with Clustered Errors."

The problem is that I want to create a nice-looking regression table to output for the user, similar to what standard Stata regressions report.  However, I cannot use the usual function "ereturn", because my program creates t-statistics and confidence intervals based on bootstrapping the t-statistic.  As I understand the "ereturn" function, it requires a vector of parameters and a variance-covariance matrix as input, and then calculates the standard errors, t-statistics, and 95% CIs itself.  This means that I cannot simply input my t-statistic p-values and 95% CIs into the "ereturn" function.  Even if I calculate bootstrapped standard errors to fill in the variances in a VCV, the t-statistics and CIs would be wrong.

Is there another function in Stata that returns tables to the user and could be used to report the results of my program?  Can I change the code of "ereturn" and save it as another program that will accept my statistics to output?  Or am I stuck with outputting the results in simple text display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complement @Nick's answer.

It should already be clear that you can write programs, be that **e-class** or **r-class**, that give similar results. Taking from his code:

```
*----- example programs -----

capture program drop whatever
program whatever, eclass 
    ereturn post
    ereturn scalar answer = 42 
end

capture program drop whatever2
program whatever2, rclass 
    return scalar answer = 42 
end

*----- use programs -----

whatever
ereturn list

whatever2
return list
```

But beware that *there are* differences between these two types, and they should be clarified reading, at least, [**[U] 18.10 Saving results**](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/u18.pdf). Choose your program type accordingly.

Now another point. You say

> The problem is that I want to create a nice-looking regression table 
>   to output for the user, similar to what standard Stata
>   regressions report. However, I cannot use the usual function
>   "ereturn",

There's no reason to think the program class will impede such tables:

```
*----- example programs -----

// first program
capture program drop whatever
program whatever, eclass 
    ereturn post
    local ans = 42
    ereturn scalar answer = `ans' 

    // table
    di as smcl as txt                ///
        _col( 7) "Whatever {c |}"    ///
        _col(22) "Value"              

    di as smcl as txt "  {hline 13}{c +}{hline 62}"

    di as smcl as txt              ///
        _col( 8) "        {c |}"   ///
        _col(23) `ans'     
end

// second program
capture program drop whatever2
program whatever2, rclass 
    local ans = 42
    return scalar answer = `ans' 

    // table
    di as smcl as txt                ///
        _col( 6) "Whatever2 {c |}"   ///
        _col(22) "Value"              

    di as smcl as txt "  {hline 13}{c +}{hline 62}"

    di as smcl as txt              ///
        _col( 8) "        {c |}"   ///
        _col(23) `ans'      
end

*----- use programs -----

whatever
ereturn list

whatever2
return list
```

If you want a table as a result, you simply use `display` (or `di`) within your program definition. There's nothing special in those tables, but they should get the point across.

You can check how StataCorp programmers and other programmers/users display tables taking a look at the .ado files they write. See `help viewsource`.

Comment: Thanks-- it looks like the best option is to build a table myself using the "display" command.  I was hoping there is a command similar to "ereturn post" that allows me to input my own t-statistics, etc... but it looks like that doesn't exist.  I'll just have to make my own nice-looking table from scratch (and maybe copying other programs!).

Answer (score 2):

Your hypothesis can easily be tested by writing some code. The facetious example here

```
program whatever, eclass 
    ereturn scalar answer = 42 
end
```

shows that an e-class program can be created that returns e-class results of one's choosing. It's no more than a common convention (for all that it makes much statistical sense) to return a variance-covariance matrix. That is not an essential part of the syntactic definition.

```
. whatever

. eret li

scalars:
         e(answer) =  42
```

Note that `ereturn` is not a Stata function, but a command. Nor could Stata functions help you out here if matters were otherwise. In Stata, functions and commmands are disjoint. Naturally, terminology is often different elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the difference between commands and functions, and the abilities of e-class programs.  I was aware that I can display my results using "display", but didn't know that ereturn can take other sorts of results besides the typical parameter vector and VCV.

Answer (score 0):

The method I ended up using to make my regression table output is the "estout" command.  "estout" allows for you to display a matrix in a pretty-looking table that is already formatted, with some relatively simple options for changing how it displays.  I hope this helps anyone who faces a similar situation.

```
estout matrix(final, fmt(%10.0g %10.0g %10.0g %12.4f %10.0g %10.0g)), ///
style(smcl) title("Model Results") mlabels("", none) modelwidth(10 10 10 6 10 10)
```

Using an already-labeled matrix that already contains the vector of coefficients, standard errors, t-values, p-values, and 95% CIs, this command produces a table that looks pretty similar to a standard Stata regression table.

Comment: Just to note that `estout` is a user-written command that must be installed separately: `ssc install estout`. You should make that clear in the command's help file.